# Foreach loop causing lag?

Tags: c#, xna

In my previous question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442959/get-an-array-of-each-pixels-color-from-texture2d-xna) I successfully found out how to read and draw a level each frame from an image.

Now that I have inputted a Player class, the player moves really choppy despite the code not doing so. I know this because if I comment the level reading code out, the player moves fine.

I think it's the foreach loop doing this. I have no idea and help would be appreciated!

Just to save you time from clicking, here's my successful level-reading code.

```
public void readLevel(string path, GraphicsDevice graphics)
{

    //GET AN ARRAY OF COLORS
    Texture2D level = Content.Load<Texture2D>(path);
    Color[] colors = new Color[level.Width * level.Height];
    level.GetData(colors);

    //READ EACH PIXEL AND DRAW LEVEL
    Color brickRGB = new Color(128, 128, 128);
    Color blankRGB = new Color(87, 0, 127);

    int placeX = 0;
    int placeY = 0;

    foreach (Color pixel in colors)
    {
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(graphics);
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        if (pixel == brickRGB)
        {
            Texture2D brick = Content.Load<Texture2D>("blocks/brick");
            spriteBatch.Draw(brick, new Rectangle(placeX, placeY, 40, 40), Color.White);

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(placeX, placeY, 40, 40);
            blocks.Add(rect);
        }
        else if (pixel == blankRGB)
        {
            Texture2D back = Content.Load<Texture2D>("titlescreen/back");
            spriteBatch.Draw(back, new Rectangle(placeX, placeY, 40, 40), Color.White);
        }

        if (placeX == 840)
        {
            placeX = 0;
            placeY += 40;
        }
        else placeX += 40;
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
```

Game.cs:

```
class Game
{
    Player player;
    LevelReader reader;
    int level = 1;

    public Game(ContentManager content)
    {
        reader = new LevelReader(content);
        player = new Player(content);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        player.Update();
    }
    public void Draw(GraphicsDevice graphics)
    {
        reader.readLevel("levels/l" + level, graphics);
        player.Draw(graphics);

    }
}
```

Comment: Loading the level texture every frame (`Content.Load`...) is probably not the best idea, performance wise. Other than that, what are some actual values for `level.Width` and `level.Height`?

Comment: The image I'm reading from is 22*15, so we're looping through the foreach loop 330 times each frame, also probably not a good idea. But I don't know an alternative, I will fix loading the level each frame though.

Comment: Unless you have an elaborate content streaming system (which I see no evidence of), you should not call `Content.Load` during gameplay and certainly not for every frame.  If it's static you should do all such operations during `LoadContent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to move the calls to `spritebatch.Begin()` and `spritebatch.End()` outside of your loop.

```
SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(graphics);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
foreach (Color pixel in colors)
    {


        if (pixel == brickRGB)
        {
            Texture2D brick = Content.Load<Texture2D>("blocks/brick");
            spriteBatch.Draw(brick, new Rectangle(placeX, placeY, 40, 40), Color.White);

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(placeX, placeY, 40, 40);
            blocks.Add(rect);
        }
        else if (pixel == blankRGB)
        {
            Texture2D back = Content.Load<Texture2D>("titlescreen/back");
            spriteBatch.Draw(back, new Rectangle(placeX, placeY, 40, 40), Color.White);
        }

        if (placeX == 840)
        {
            placeX = 0;
            placeY += 40;
        }
        else placeX += 40;

    }
spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: -_- I feel dumb now, well at least my problem was fixed quick. Thanks so much! I

Comment: You're still loading the same brick via `Content.Load` for each iteration of `foreach`.  Performance will suffer!